# Bachelor thesis in mathematical physics.

Tags: soft-question, advice

After 3 years of study of mathematics and physics, I wish to write my bachelor thesis, starting in September, on a mathematical physics subject. I have prior mathematical knowledge of differential geometry and algebraic topology, functional analysis and complex analysis. I don't necessary have to come up with the topic myself, although it is always better to write something on your personal interests.

I was wondering whether one of you knows about any interesting topic in mathematical physics  suited for a bachelor thesis, the level of the topic may be at graduate level since I have 4 months of full time writing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: At my university, there is a chair for mathematical physics, see http://www10.mathematik.uni-wuerzburg.de/index.php?path=research/maphy. Maybe you'll find some topics for the Bachelor thesis there! Good luck! :)

Comment: You should speak with faculty for some guidance; they can help with interesting questions or readings. Their experience and time is very valuable, so make the most of every meeting.